# How to start anaconda navigator when error?

Tags: installation, anaconda

I try to open Anaconda navigator from the app and from the terminal and neither works.Terminal displays the errors and never stops running. :

- QMimeDatabase: Error loading internal MIME data
  An error has been encountered at line 1 of : Premature end of document.:
  2023-08-06 15:29:09,459 - ERROR **init**.global_exception_logger:20
  'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 11: invalid continuation byte
- UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 11: invalid continuation byte
  QEventDispatcherWin32::wakeUp: Failed to post a message (Handle de fenÛtre non valide.)
  QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread

I am no very at ease with terminal and everything, if you could take it into account in your answer
Thanks a lot !

[capture of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEztH.png)

I have already tried among others :

- conda update --all
- conda update navigator-updater
- anaconda-navigator --reset
  I have also checked that anaconda is well installed with $ conda list
  [conda info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY7SS.png)